# Android Studio build problems

Tags: android, android-studio

Java 8 language support, as requested by 'android.enableD8.desugaring= true' in your gradle.properties file, is not supported when 'android.useDexArchive= false'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Java 8 language features in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423057/how-to-enable-java-8-language-features-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you used tinker with old version.  You can return your

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

maybe you can upgrade tinker version but  I didn't verify it.

I used tinker verison

```
implementation 'com.tencent.tinker:tinker-android-lib:1.9.6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add :

```
android.useDexArchive= false
```

In  `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in gradle.properties

```
android.enableD8=true
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

Add this line in gradle.properties
android.useDexArchive=true